# Bulk copy from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: c#

I'm trying to copy tables form a MS Access database into a SQL Server database.

This is the code:

```
private static void BulkCopyAccessToSQLServer(string sql, string destinationTable,string fileName)
{
  using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
  {
     using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", fileName)))
     using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
     using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
     {
         cmd.Connection.Open();
         adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240;
         adapter.Fill(dt);
         adapter.Dispose();
     }
     using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connStr))
     {
         conn2.Open();
         using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn2))
         {
             copy.DestinationTableName = destinationTable;
             copy.BatchSize = 1000;
             copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 240;
             copy.WriteToServer(dt);
             copy.NotifyAfter = 1000;
         }
     }
  }
}
```

Calling this function like this...

```
BulkCopyAccessToSQLServer("select * from Table1", "Table1", "C:\\db.‌​accdb");
```

I get the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Could not find file 'C:\db.‌​accdb'.
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>   at WebService.BulkCopyAccessToSQLServer(String sql, String destinationTable, String fileName)
>   at WebService.Import()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the database `C:\db.accdb` exists?

Comment: ive done this through sql management but need to do it through my code

Comment: could you tell me how to schedule it through management studio then?

Comment: See: [Schedule a SSIS package with SQL Server Agent](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/)

Comment: isnt it only for sql server 2005 onwards? i got 2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the bulk import from a web service from the looks of your stack trace.

Does the web service process have sufficient rights to access `C:\db.accdb`?

Comment: yeh i have moved the db to several location but still same error

Comment: @Beginner: You need to check the ACL (access control list) of the file, and ensure you contains an entry for your service login. For instance if you were running under the application pool `Blah`, it could be `IIS AppPool\Blah`.